# Can Eclipse auto-complete import statement without adding wildcard?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I'm typing import statements in Eclipse a list of auto-complete options are given, but when I select one, it adds a wildcard for the whole package, e.g. `org.apache.*`, but I want to auto-complete the just the package name and continue typing a sub-package or class, e.g. `org.apache.log4j.Logger`

Answer (score 7):

Eclipse has a setting for the number of imports needed in order to stop listing the classes one by one and use the `package.*` syntax instead.

You can change that setting by going to Window>Preferences>Java>Code Style>Organize Imports.

Put a large number into the edit boxes at the bottom.

Comment: While a useful tip, I don't think it addresses the question. When typing `import` statements, that setting doesn't seem to have any impact; you always get the wildcard import for the package you select.

Comment: @E-Riz The code formatter needs to be enabled/active, though I think importing everything individually only adds noise. What this post helped me do was find the option so that I could enter a `1` there and always get wildcard imports automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than typing individual `import` statements by hand, consider just typing the names of classes where you need them, then using Content Assist (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> on OS X) and let Eclipse auto-insert the import statement for you automatically. It won't use a wildcard import unless you've configured it to do that at a certain threshold (see @f1sh's answer).

Comment: And Ctrl+Shift+O will fix import statements at any time.